# React Native - Update Parent State in Child with Dynamic Key

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am very new to both Javascript and React Native, and I am trying update a parent's state by using a callback function using a dynamic key to avoid writing multiple functions.

In the parent component, I pass this function to the child to child to update the parent's state based on user text input. **This code achieves the desired result**.

In Parent:

```
_setAge = (value) => {
this.setState({age: value})}

<ChildComponent name = 'Update Age' _setAge = { this._setAge.bind(this) } />
```

In Child:

```
//Other child code
<TextInput onChangeText = { (input) => {this.props._setAge(input)} }
//Etc.
```

However, I am looking for a way to pass a desired state key from the parent to the child to update the state dynamically. I have tried the following:

In Parent:

```
const ageKey = 'age'

_setAge = (value, stateKey) => {
this.setState({ [stateKey]: value })}

<ChildComponent name = 'Update Age' _setAge = { this._setAge.bind(this) } stateKey = ageKey } />
```

In Child:

```
//Other child code
<TextInput onChangeText = { (input) => this.props._setAge(input, this.props.stateKey)
//Etc.
```

However this doesn't work. My current work around is writing 6 functions for my 6 child components, each updating the desire state. However, while this would work for my basic app, I am looking for a way that is more scalable for future projects. Thank you!

Comment: I put these snipits into a sandbox pretty much as is and it seems to work, maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem?
https://codesandbox.io/s/95v45pj7w

Comment: Hi SpeedOfRound! Thank you, it's working now. I probably was resolved an issue I did not know about while comparing your code to mine. I appreciate the time

Answer (score 0):

> > In Parent
> >     Instead of passing stateKey in props on child key directly pass the state key in onChageText method in child. the code would look like this->>>>

```
_setAge = (value, stateKey) => {  
this.setState({ [stateKey]: value })}

<ChildComponent name = 'Update Age' _setAge = {this._setAge} /> // providing no statekey here
```

> > Inside the child

```
<TextInput onChangeText = { (input) => this.props._setAge(input, 'age') } 
   // here i know statekey for each child so i directly pass the key from child so i dont have to pass it as a props and then access it
```

Comment: Hi md.warish Ansari thanks for the response. Unfortunately I am trying to avoid hard coding the key in the child component because I am re-using it 6 times. I should have been more clear with my variable names. I would like to pass in the key from the parent so each time I use the child component, I can customize which state of the parent it updates.

Comment: @holdenmaudlin I recommend putting your "magic number" into a constants file and importing it as needed